# Jquery Sliding Div works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing some code that makes a div slide to the left or the right of the page depending on some key press (left or right arrows). Here is my script.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var $inner = $('.inner-cover');
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
     $inner.css({
       position: 'fixed',
       top: $inner.offset().top,
       left: $inner.offset().left
     }).animate({left:'100%'}, 1000);
   }
   if (e.keyCode == 37){ 
     $inner.css({
       position: 'fixed',
       top: $inner.offset().top,
       right: $inner.offset().right
     }).animate({right:'100%'}, 1000);
   }
});
```

and here is a link to it in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/e32A3/

I have a few questions about it that I'd really like answered because I don't seem to understand this properly.

Why does the slide function only work one or two times?

Why do I need to put

```
$inner.css({}).animate({left:'100%'},1000);
```

I tried

```
$inner.animate({left:100%},1000);
```

and it did not work

Also how would I stop it in the center? I'm figuring that I have to do something along the lines of

```
animate({left:($(window).width()-$inner.width())/2)},1000);
```

but again I've tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: for the 2nd, because the `position` should be set to `fixed` or `absolute` or `relative` to make the `left` take effect.

Comment: also note that the `offset()` returns an object which does not have the `right` or `bottom` property, it just has the `left` and `top`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 if (e.keyCode == 37){ 
 $inner.css({
   position: 'fixed',
   top: $inner.offset().top
 }).animate({left:'-100%'}, 1000);}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e32A3/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
var $inner = $('.inner-cover');
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    $inner.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: $inner.offset().top,
        left: $inner.offset().left
    }).animate({
        left: '100%',
        right: 'auto'
    }, 1000);
}
if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    $inner.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: $inner.offset().top,
    }).animate({
        right: '100%',
        left: 'auto'
    }, 1000);
}
});
```

Added `right` to `"auto"` instead of `offset().right` , there is nothing as `offset().right`. Offset contains only top and left values.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/e32A3/2/

Answer (score 0):

*Why does the slide function only work one or two times?*

Because in the second run it has already property "left:100%"

*Why do I need to put*

Because setting "left" or "right" will take effect only if position of element setted to fixed/absolute/relative

*Also how would I stop it in the center?*

To set in the center set

```
$inner.animate({left:window.(innerWidth-$inner.width)/2+"px"})
```

Finally you need to operate with one of attr "left" or "right" and set the position of element in CSS

JS:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
var $inner = $('.inner-cover');
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    $inner.animate({left:($(window).width() - $inner.width())+"px"}, 1000);
    //this to set on middle//$inner.animate({left:($(window).width() - $inner.width())/2+"px"}, 1000);
}
if (e.keyCode == 37){ 
 $inner.animate({left:0}, 1000);
}
});
```

CSS:

```
.inner-cover {
position:fixed;
width:200px;
left:50%;
top:50%;
background-color:green;
}
```